# Turbolinks 5 - tearing down 3rd party widget (async)

Tags: google-tag-manager, turbolinks

I am using FreshChat widget and I'm losing it when performing cached visit. The thing is that the destroy() function of the widget is async, so while I execute it on any event such as 'click' or 'before-visit', the widget is still persisted when the caching operation executes. So what I get is a cached page with an initialised widget, this breaks the widget and I can't re-initiate it. 
If I manually destroy it in console(before every visit), then everything is fine.

The question is - how can I make sure that once I make a visit, the widget is destroyed BEFORE the current page is cached?

Notes:

- The widget is executed from google tag manager, using dataLayer custom event
- 'before-cache' event would not help since again, it's an async operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
function beforeVisit( event ) {
  if (!window.turbolinksVisitFlag) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (window.fcWidget ) {
    window.fcWidget.destroy();
  }
  window.turbolinksVisitFlag = true;
  setTimeout(function(){Turbolinks.visit(event.data.url);}, 500);
}
```

So now I intercept every visit, do my stuff, and manually initiate next visit with a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I checked if the widget is still initialized, then I would destroy it using the below flush_freshchat method and reload the script to initialize window.fcWidget again

```
  function initFreshChat() {
    window.fcWidget.init({
      token: "<%= Settings::FRESHCHAT_TOKEN %>",
      host: "<%= Settings::FRESHCHAT_HOST %>"
  }); 

  function flush_freshchat(){
    delete window.fcWidget;
    delete window.history.pushState_fc_observer;
    delete window.history.replaceState_fc_observer;
    delete window.history.pushState;
    delete window.history.replaceState;
  }

(function(d, id) {
    var fcJS;
    freshchat_sdk = d.getElementById(id);
    if (freshchat_sdk) {
      freshchat_sdk.remove();
      if(window.fcWidget.isInitialized()){
        flush_freshchat();
      }
    }
    fcJS = d.createElement('script');
    fcJS.id = id;
    fcJS.async = true;
    fcJS.src = 'https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js';
    fcJS.onload = initFreshChat;
    d.head.appendChild(fcJS);
}(document, 'freshchat-js-sdk'));
```